# Schedule selector error

Tags: c++, windows-8, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to port my iPhone app to windows 8, I have a problem with this line (it's objective-c) :

```
[self schedule:@selector(fire:)];
```

The equivalent on c++ should be :

```
this->schedule(schedule_selector(AirScene::fire));
```

Where AirScene is the name of my class, but I have this error returning by Visual Studio 2012 :

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

So, in other words the function schedule(selector) is not found. It's strange because I have no problem with unschedule method, do you have any idea please ?

**EDIT : AirScene.h**

```
#include "cocos2d.h" 
#include "Box2D\Box2D.h"
#include "AirSceneDelegate.h"

class AirScene : public cocos2d::CCLayer {
    public:
        AirScene::~AirScene(void);

        // Here's a difference. Method 'init' in cocos2d-x returns bool, instead of returning 'id' in cocos2d-iphone
        virtual bool init();  
        static cocos2d::CCScene* scene();
        LAYER_NODE_FUNC(AirScene);

        //Methods
        void selectSpriteForTouch(cocos2d::CCPoint touchLocation);
        cocos2d::CCPoint checkPuckPosition(cocos2d::CCPoint newPosition);
        void panForTranslation(cocos2d::CCPoint translation);
        void updateQuestion(string question);
        void restoreScene();
        void enableScreensaver();
        void disableScreensaver(cocos2d::CCPoint touchPosition);

        //Setters
        void setDelegate(AirSceneDelegate *delegate);

    private:
        // Init
        void initBackground(cocos2d::CCSize winSize);
        void initPuck(cocos2d::CCSize winSize, cocos2d::CCPoint position);
        void initHoles(cocos2d::CCSize winSize);
        void initQuestion(cocos2d::CCSize winSize);

        // Methods
        void fire(cocos2d::ccTime dt = 0);
        void updateHoles(cocos2d::ccTime dt);
        void validateVote(bool isPositiveVote);
        float getVelocity();        

        // Attributes

        ...

        //Delegate
        AirSceneDelegate* _delegate;
};
```

**AirScene.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "AirScene.h"

USING_NS_CC;

#pragma region Delete

AirScene::~AirScene(void)
{
    ///TODO : DELETE ALL
    delete(_delegate);
    _delegate = 0;
}

#pragma endregion Delete

#pragma region Init

CCScene* AirScene::scene()
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    CCScene *scene = CCScene::node();

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object
    AirScene *layer = AirScene::node();

    // add layer as a child to scene
    scene->addChild(layer);

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool AirScene::init()
{
    // Super Init
    if (!CCLayer::init())
        return false;

    //Init Attributes
    screenSaverMode = false;
    hasVoted = false;
    schedule = false;
    _delegate = 0;
    _selSprite = NULL;

    //Create World
    b2Vec2 gravity = b2Vec2(0, 0);
    _world = new b2World(gravity);

    CCSize size = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();

    //Inits
    AirScene::initBackground(size);
    AirScene::initPuck(size, ccp(512, 200));
    AirScene::initHoles(size);
    AirScene::initQuestion(size);


    return true;
}

// Init Background and set walls
void AirScene::initBackground(CCSize winSize)
{
    ...
}


/** Init Puck : create puck body and shape */
void AirScene::initPuck(CCSize winSize, CCPoint position)
{
    ...
}


void AirScene::initHoles(CCSize winSize)
{
    ...
}


// Set Question Label
void AirScene::initQuestion(CCSize winSize)
{    
    ...
}

#pragma endregion Init

#pragma region Private

void AirScene::fire(ccTime dt)
{
    _world->Step(dt, 8, 8);

    //CCSprite *ballData = ((CCSprite *)_body->GetUserData()) 
    ((CCSprite *)_body->GetUserData())->setPosition(ccp(_body->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, _body->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO));
    _puckShadow->setPosition(ccp(((CCSprite *)_body->GetUserData())->getPosition().x + 2, ((CCSprite *)_body->GetUserData())->getPosition().y - 2));

    if (screenSaverMode)
        AirScene::updateHoles(0);
}

//Ajust Glow Effect and Validate Vote
void AirScene::updateHoles(cocos2d::ccTime dt)
{
    ...
}

float AirScene::getVelocity()
{
    ...
}

void AirScene::validateVote(bool isPositiveVote)
{
    ...
}

#pragma endregion Private

#pragma region Public

void AirScene::selectSpriteForTouch(CCPoint touchLocation)
{
    ...
}

// Check if the puck is not outside the view
CCPoint AirScene::checkPuckPosition(CCPoint newPosition)
{
    ...
}

// Move Puck
void AirScene::panForTranslation(CCPoint translation)
{
    ...
}

// Update Question
void AirScene::updateQuestion(string question)
{
    ...
}

void AirScene::restoreScene()
{
    ...
}

void AirScene::enableScreensaver()
{
    screenSaverMode = true;
    CCSize winSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();

    //Unschedule actions
    this->unscheduleAllSelectors();

    //Delete Puck
    CCPoint puckPosition = _puck->getPosition();
    _puck->removeAllChildrenWithCleanup(true);
    _puck->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
    _puckShadow->removeAllChildrenWithCleanup(true);
    _puckShadow->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
    _world->DestroyBody(_body);
    delete(_puck);
    delete(_puckShadow);

    //RecreatePuck
    this->initPuck(winSize, ccp(512, 200));

    //Impulse
    _body->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(0, 0));

    /** ERROR IS CAUSED BY THIS LINE */ 
    this->schedule(schedule_selector(AirScene::fire));
}

void AirScene::disableScreensaver(cocos2d::CCPoint touchPosition)
{
}

#pragma endregion Public


#pragma region Getters & Setters

void  AirScene::setDelegate(AirSceneDelegate *delegate)
{
    _delegate = delegate; 
}

#pragma endregion Getters & Setters
```

Comment: does the fire method take 1 argument?

Comment: could you post more of the class file? Take out piece that cannot be shown but do show methods

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, @LearnCocos2D, yes Fire can take one optional argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed.**

The version of cocos 2d which is used for windows 8 template is an old version, so the good way to schedule a selector is this one :

```
CCScheduler::sharedScheduler()->scheduleSelector(schedule_selector(AirScene::fire), this, 0, false);
```